# Add random images to labels

Tags: excel, vba, userform

UserForm 2 = 36 buttons (btn1 thru btn36)  Each button has an image on it.
When I click the "ADD" button I would like for three randon images that are on the buttons to show up in UserForm 1 three lables where it says Random Image 1.

[image: Right now when I click the "ADD" button, it brings up UserForm1. When I click "OK" on UserForm1 I would like to state which three buttons were inserted into UserForm1 on a spreadsheet.]

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of your question. I suggest you provide screen-shots of your form, a single well structured question, and ways you have tried to solve them yourself.

Comment: @Alain:  I added a sample screen shot of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a random button image you'll need to use the collection Me.Controls on the form. For example:

```
Dim cCont As Control
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    'DO STUFF HERE
Next cCont
```

If you put a watch on the variable cCont, you can see all the properties each control has. First, you will have to filter out the controls that are buttons. You will then have to look at the image property for that button to grab it and set on the second form.

Finally, to introduce a random element, just use the Rand() function. This will return a random number between 0 and 1. If you multiply this by the number of controls in Me.Controls, and round it to an integer, you will get a random control. Just make sure that the control you indexed is a button, and you can use that button's image as one of the random images.